# Is there any technical difference between To and CC field in Email?

Tags: email, yahoo

I Know the below things

To: is to the person who is receiving the email or taking action regarding email received

CC: is "Carbon Copy" which basically is for information so that they know the "To" person recieved the email and the action should be taken on the mail received

BCC: Blind Carbon Copy meaning that the others who recieved the email will not know that the BCC person got the email.

But My actual doubt is that,

Yahoo is blocking the mails received by there user, ***send using third party tools/servers.*** [Here is more info from Yahoo](http://postmaster.yahoo.com/errors/postmaster-28.html)

When a send a mail from some site in the below format

```
From: xxx@yahoo.com
To  : yyy@yahoo.com
```

Sender is receiving error message.

But if i send in below format yahoo is accepting mails

**Edit**

```
From: xxx@yahoo.com
To  : zzz@gmail.com
CC  : yyy@yahoo.com
```

Comment: This question is off-topic because it has absolutely nothing to do with programming.

Comment: Of course there is a technical difference .. it's a different field. And all recipient servers get to see both of these fields. It may be the case that including the sender in the CC trips up/disables the Yahoo! Spam Guard (although I just noticed that in the 2nd example the recipient is at Gmail, not Yahoo!)

Comment: @user2864740 I think that's the point of the question. I read "technical difference" as "difference in how they are handled by the various programs and protocols that make e-mail work."

Comment: @ssdecontrol Then, in a direct statement this time, to the OP: don't waste valuable title space with a rhetorical question.

Comment: @user2864740 I hardly think nitpicking over the difference between "Is there any" and "What is the" is worth a belittling and unhelpful comment on a question with a non-obvious answer.

Answer (score 0):

The error you mention is purely caused by a policy with Yahoo that states, from the link you give,

> Your message wasn't delivered because Yahoo was unable to verify that
>   it came from a legitimate email sender.

So Yahoo's concern is to make sure spam is not sent using forged addresses unknowingly to the legitimate address owner.

If you include the `CC` field with the same address as `From`, it means at least the "maybe forged" sender is receiving a copy of the sent email. And that seems to be sufficient for Yahoo to accept to forward your email.